# Pasr or present tense?

Tags: grammar

this story is written by my 6 years old son :

> Once upon a time there was a world of programming and it had a game called minecraft , it was with programming but a glitch happened and it created a monster called  a creeper , and that's how they got into minecraft .

I am asking about ( it was with programming ) Can he change it to ( it was a programmed game ) or ( it is a programmed game ) ?

as he means that the game was written using the java programming language .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me answer this two different ways.

First, could this have been a story written by a six-year-old native speaker of English?  Yes it could.  It contains the exact kind of narrative structure and semantic errors that you would expect from a six-year-old writer.  From this perspective there is really nothing wrong with it, as an adult can understand what your son is trying to say.

Second, is it natural English?  Not really, but it's difficult to correct as I'm not entirely sure what your son means by "it was with programming".  If, as you say, he means "it was a programmed game" then sure, you could replace one with the other -- but it doesn't really improve the story all that much.

If on the other hand by "world of programming" he means a "world inside a computer simulation" (which is what I think he might be saying) then your edit is not an improvement, as it changes the intended meaning.

If I was writing this as an adult, of course, I would completely restructure it to something like:

> Once upon a time there was a game called Minecraft which existed entirely as a computer simulation. One day a glitch happened and it created a monster called a Creeper, which is how they got into the game.

But I like your son's version better.

Comment: Hello i’m Eyad i’m the one who made this story and "world of programming" i wanted to say : there is a planet and everything inside this planet is made by programming and one of these things is a game called minecraft .And then the rest of the story . From Eyad. also i’m Egyptian and thanks for your opinion

Comment: @Salmaadel  Hi Eyad, I know what Minecraft is.  My nephew played quite a lot, although I never really got into it.